# MariaDB LOAD XML much slower than MySQL

Tags: mariadb, database-performance

I am testing MariaDB for a possible replacement of a MySQL data warehouse.  This data warehouse is rebuilt nightly from a legacy database.

The basic process is to generate XML documents/files from the legacy database and then use DROP TABLE, create table from DDL, LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '*xml file*'.  A few of the XML files are 60-100 megabytes (about 300K rows).  On MySQL these tables take a couple minutes.  On MariaDB these tables take significantly longer (e.g. 83 megabyte XML file requires 16 minutes on MariaDB, MySQL less than 1 minute), and the times seem to grow exponentially with file size.

I have read and followed the KB topic *How to Quickly Insert Data Into MariaDB* and have tried the suggestions there with no real change.  Since the MariaDB tables are dropped and recreated immediately before the LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE, several performance improvements should be triggered.

I have not tried LOCK TABLE yet.

What can I try to improve performance?  Don't want to return to MySQL but this issue is a deal killer.

Environment is RHEL 8, MariaDB 10.5.16

Used DISABLE KEYS/LOAD.../ENABLE KEYS with no apparent benefit.

Increased max_allowed_packet_size with no effect.

Comment: Are you inserting into an innodb or aria/myisam table? InnoDB had performance improvement in [10.7+](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-innodb-bulk-insert/). What innodb_log_file_size/innodb_buffer_pool_size/[innodb_log_buffer_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_buffer_size) do you have?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size 134217728
innodb_log_file_size 100663296
innodb_log_buffer_size 16777216

Comment: Also,the created tables have no foreign keys defined (planning to add these in the future).

Comment: Installed version 10.10.  That helped a bit.  I am not sure which parameters I need to tune, and to what values.

Comment: Additional DB information request from your MariaDB, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Data from your first note is at https://justpaste.it/c82q8

Comment: The single query was a LOAD XML INFILE to bulk load a table (from our legacy DB).  XML document is 161MB representing 324403 rows.  It did complete after several hours.  The mariadb server was at the top of TOP for the entire time with CPU use of ~99.5%.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Client decided MariaDB experiment is over